# Change of Variables Polars

Tags: calculus

Let $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

Find $\frac{dr}{dt}$?

I think it is 
$$
\frac{dr}{dt}= \frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{-1/2}\left[2x \frac{dx}{dt} + 2y \frac{dy}{dt}\right],
$$
would this be correct?

Comment: Not quite. Remember that $r^2 = x^2+y^2$ means that $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: Another way to approach this is to use the fact $$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$. Forgive me if this was how you computed it originally ;).

Comment: Now that the question has been edited in response to a previous comment, the answer is yes, the result is correct.